# Implement a friendship model with has_and_belongs_to_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have user model and I am using `has_and_belongs_to_many` on Rails to make a relation between user and friend model.
User can has many friends and friend can has many friends. I need to get all friends of specific user, how can I do that?

In **user.rb** file:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :friendships, class_name: "User", join_table:  :friendships,
                          foreign_key: :user_id,
                          association_foreign_key: :friend_user_id}
```

In **20180309142447_create_friendships_table.rb** file:

```
class CreateFriendshipsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :friendships, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :friend_user_id
    end

    add_index(:friendships, [:user_id, :friend_user_id], :unique => true)
    add_index(:friendships, [:friend_user_id, :user_id], :unique => true)
  end
end
```

I need to get all friends of specific user, how can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want something like facebook ? User requests friendship and then the other user has to accpet ?

Comment: I can share this implementation if you like

Comment: yes you can ,
it's like : i want to display all friends of user 
and add friends to user

Comment: have you tried `user.friendships` ?

Comment: But this works only one way, so it`s more a "follow"

Comment: Do you already have data in it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Implementing a friendship between two users**

I assume you are willing to implement a friendship pattern like Facebook:

1. User requests friendship for another user
2. Other other has to accept the friendship request
3. Only after these two steps the users are real friends

---

For this we need a friendship model which replaces your `has_many_and_belongs_to`-built in function. The friendship models will help us to identify active and pending friendship requests between users. The friendship model only has a user (initiator) and a friend (whom the user sent the request).

Scenario:

1. You send a request to Joe -> friendship model created, you are the 'user', joe is the 'friend'
2. Joe accepts your friendship -> friendship model created, joe is the 'user', you are the 'friend'
3. With 2 helper functions `active_friends` and `pending_friends` you can get the data for your views or API

---

```
# new migration
# $ rails g migration create_friendships
def change
  create_table :friendships do |t|
    t.integer :user_id
    t.integer :friend_id
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

create a new friendship model

```
# friendship.rb
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base

  # - RELATIONS
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

  # - VALIDATIONS
  validates_presence_of :user_id, :friend_id
  validate :user_is_not_equal_friend
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:friend_id]

  def is_mutual
    self.friend.friends.include?(self.user)
  end

  private
  def user_is_not_equal_friend
    errors.add(:friend, "can't be the same as the user") if self.user == self.friend
  end

end
```

in your User model you can handle the friendships rails-like

```
# user.rb
has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :friends, through: :friendships
```

to get the friendships someoneelse sent to "you"

```
has_many :received_friendships, class_name: 'Friendship', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
has_many :received_friends, through: :received_friendships, source: 'user'

def active_friends
  friends.select{ |friend| friend.friends.include?(self) }  
end

def pending_friends
  friends.select{ |friend| !friend.friends.include?(self) }  
end
```

Comment: good work , but iam using in user Model :
and_belongs_to_many :friendships,class_name: "User",join_table:  :friendships,
                          foreign_key: :user_id,
                          association_foreign_key: :friend_user_id
and it create a second table 
how can i retrieve friends of user to display

Comment: and i have no friendship model

Comment: Maybe you should have one ? :)

Comment: Okay I will add Model and will come back with answer :D

Comment: @NetSim how is it going ?

Comment: Yes , it is going Now thank you very much
i created Friend Table

Comment: wow.. that's quite detailed. Thank you so much.